# Python: backslashes (\u...) in files

Tags: python-3.x, escaping, python-unicode

I have a file with unicode characters in the \u format. I want to write them to another file as ordinary unicode strings. But I can't get the backslash to be interpreted as an escape character.

So I have this in a file, for example,
`\u1203\u1208\u1208 \u0074\u00E4\u0068\u0061\u006C\u00E4\u006C\u00E4`,
which should print out like this.

```
>>> print("\u1203\u1208\u1208 \u0074\u00E4\u0068\u0061\u006C\u00E4\u006C\u00E4")
ሃለለ tähalälä
```

But instead I get this.

```
>>> with open('ti.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)

\u1203\u1208\u1208 \u0074\u00E4\u0068\u0061\u006C\u00E4\u006C\u00E4
```

I've tried every combination of `str()`, `repr()`, `encode().decode()` that I can think of. But those backslashes still end up as backslashes.

Comment: Read the whole file (if it is possible)  as binary and use .decode("utf-8").

Answer (score 1):

### Best answer (2021+):

- Use the built-in **codecs** library which exists since Python 2.4+: https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codecs.decode
- Example:

```py
import codecs

# This is True (successfully decoded):
print(codecs.decode(r"\u1234", "unicode_escape") == "\u1234")
```

*With this answer, you don't need to convert strings into `bytes`-type objects to be able to decode them. It's a replacement for the bad "str.encode().decode()" pattern that many people wrongly use.*

Answer (score -1):

You want the built-in [`unicode_escape` text encoding](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#text-encodings).

First, you should open the file in binary mode (`'rb'`) so that it will let you call `.decode()` on the data. Then just do `line.decode('unicode_escape')`.

Modified code:

```py
with open('ti.txt', 'rb') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line.decode('unicode_escape'))
```

In action:

```
$ cat ti.txt
\u1203\u1208\u1208 \u0074\u00E4\u0068\u0061\u006C\u00E4\u006C\u00E4

$ python parse_unicode_escape.py
ሃለለ tähalälä
```