# Read from file with mixed unicode characters and replace string (python)

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8

Here is the file content:

```
H\u00f6gskolan
Högskolan
```

(Note: `\u00f6` is actually `ö`)

I want to replace all `ö` characters with `o`, and save it to a new file.
The regular string replace doesn't work as expected.

```
with open("test.txt", encoding="utf-8") as f:
  content = f.read()
replacedContent = content.replace("ö", "o")
with open("testOutput.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
  f.write(replacedContent)
```

testOutput.txt file content:

```
H\u00f6gskolan
Hogskolan
```

---

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60029479/python-backslashes-u-in-files) but its solution didn't work as well:

```
import codecs

with open("test.txt", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    content = f.read()
content = codecs.decode(content, "unicode_escape")
replacedContent = content.replace("ö", "o")
with open("testOutput.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(replacedContent)
```

testOutput.txt file content:

```
Hogskolan
HÃ¶gskolan
```

---

Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find any library function that already handles what you are requesting, so I just parse the raw unicode signatures with regex and replace them with their actual values

```py
import re


def convert_mixed(from_file, to_file):
    f = open(from_file, "r")
    content = f.read()
    f.close()
    for x in re.findall(r"\\u([\da-f]{4})", content):
        content = content.replace(f"\\u{x}", chr(int(x, 16)))

    f = open(to_file, "w")
    f.write(content.replace("ö", "o"))


convert_mixed("file.txt", "out.txt")
```